# Exibir outro valor na tooltip de um gráfico D3

Tags: javascript, tooltip, d3.js

Estava fazendo uma visualização e precisava exibir um valor diferente na `tooltip` que ela exibe. A visualização é totalmente baseada nesse modelo: http://bl.ocks.org/mstanaland/6100713, e exibe os valores de cada barra. Eu queria verificar se existe a possibilidade de exibir também o nome do rótulo de cada valor (no exemplo, seria o nome de cada fruta), mas não entendo muito de D3/javascript e todas as tentativas que fiz foram frustradas. Alguém teria como me dar uma luz?

Comment: Poste o código que você já fez para que possamos entender/ajudar.

Comment: Oi, Leonardo. No caso, o código é só uma adaptação desse link que eu mandei pra vocês. Só mudei os valores, mas o restante deixei absolutamente igual

Comment: Se é uma adaptação, poste a mesma para facilitar

Comment: O código tá excedendo o limite de caracteres, mas o link é esse aqui: http://noelowpoo.zz.mu/teste/visu1/todas.html